# Blender 2.81 viewport laggy on 2018 Mac mini

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I switched to Blender not too long ago and am really enjoying it! I just updated to 2.81 which is causing some major lag when viewing a scene (Cycles). The cursor starts to slow down and I can't properly click anything in the software. I did not have this issue with Blender 2.8.

I'm on a 2018 Mac mini with the following specs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfKBL.png

How can I fix it?

Have a good day:)